# How to convert a column with null values to datetime format?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, type-conversion

How I convert the df to pandas datetime datatype? (with null value)

```
datet = pd.DataFrame(['2018-09-07 00:00:00','2017-09-15 00:00:00',''],columns=['Mycol'])

datet['Mycol'] = datet['Mycol'].apply(lambda x: 
                                dt.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

But it returns error:
    ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

How can I resolve that error? (keep the null as blank)

Thanks!

Comment: You have an empty in your datecolumn

Comment: Yes, I know. So how can I transfer to the datetime and ignore the null?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just do:

```
datet['Mycol'] = pd.to_datetime(datet['Mycol'], errors='coerce')
```

This will automatically convert the null to an `NaT` value.

Output:

```
0   2018-09-07
1   2017-09-15
2          NaT
```

Comment: What if I want to raise errors when there is an invalid format, but only convert null values to `NaT`? I guess I will have to write a custom function for that using `apply`.

Answer (score 0):

Its because your third column contains an empty string. Remove that and it works. It cant convert the empty string with the match format.

```
datet = pd.DataFrame(['2018-09-07 00:00:00','2017-09-15 00:00:00'],columns=['Mycol'])

datet['Mycol'] = datet['Mycol'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Comment: As I said, I want to keep the null value, but thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I missed that comment :)